# Access a local JSON object using a js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using a js file to try and access a local JSON file. But it is not working. Even if I am using the correct url, still the code fails to retrieve data from the JSON object.

**js file:**

```
var pieData = (function() {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/pwash/js/pie.json",
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            },
            'error': function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return json;
    })();

    alert(pieData[0].value)
```

**json:**

```
[
                {
                    "value": 200,
                    "color":"#30a5ff",
                    "highlight": "#62b9fb",
                    "label": "Blue"
                },
                {
                    "value": 50,
                    "color": "#ffb53e",
                    "highlight": "#fac878",
                    "label": "Orange"
                },
                {
                    "value": 100,
                    "color": "#1ebfae",
                    "highlight": "#3cdfce",
                    "label": "Teal"
                },
                {
                    "value": 120,
                    "color": "#f9243f",
                    "highlight": "#f6495f",
                    "label": "Red"
                }
];
```

I am unable to understand where in the given am I going wrong.

Comment: Please provide the error message. It could  be a CORS problem.

Comment: is there any error in your console

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: your json file has error. your json is not valid. it has semicolon at the end. please remove it and try.

Comment: No there are no errors printed on the console. But the error function in the ajax is invoked. and that prints the data object. Thats all. @JYoThI.

Comment: And @johannesp here is that output: 
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), 11 more… }  chart-data.js:14:11
TypeError: pieData is null[Learn More]  chart-data.js:20:2
 <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/pwash/js/chart-data.js:20:2

Comment: @Dinesh Thanks man, that worked. Now I feel stupid for even posting the question. :\

Comment: @SumitRoy i answered here. pls accept

Comment: The `error` handler has **three** parameters: `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, **String errorThrown** )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your json file has error. your json is not valid. it has semicolon at the end. please remove it and try.

Answer (score 0):

access local json object using path to it not http
most likely in your case:

```
"./static/pwash/js/pie.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this sort and sweet

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/pwash/js/pie.json', function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
```

json file :

```
{
  "items": [

            {
                "value": 200,
                "color":"#30a5ff",
                "highlight": "#62b9fb",
                "label": "Blue"
            },
            {
                "value": 50,
                "color": "#ffb53e",
                "highlight": "#fac878",
                "label": "Orange"
            },
            {
                "value": 100,
                "color": "#1ebfae",
                "highlight": "#3cdfce",
                "label": "Teal"
            },
            {
                "value": 120,
                "color": "#f9243f",
                "highlight": "#f6495f",
                "label": "Red"
            }
       ]
}
```